# RxJava - Creating a GroupByUntilChanged Operator?

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming

I am trying to create my own RxJava operator called `groupByUntilChanged()`. It will function like a `groupBy()` but the emissions are assumed to be in an order based on the key. So the moment the key value changes, it completes that `GroupedObservable` and moves on to the next `GroupedObservable` for the next key.

Here is my work so far. I use the first letter of each `String` as the key. This seems to work fine until I throw an "A" `String` at the end.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Observable<String> items =
                Observable.just("Alpha","Adam","Apple","Beta","Brick","Bridge","Bat","Gamma","Gorilla","Axe");

        Func1<String,String> keyExtractor = s -> s.substring(0,1);

        items.compose(orderedGroupBy(keyExtractor))
                .flatMap(grp -> grp.toList())
                .subscribe(System.out::println);

    }

    public static <T,K> Observable.Transformer<T,GroupedObservable<K,T>> orderedGroupBy(Func1<T,K> keySelector) {
        return obs -> obs.groupBy(keySelector)
                .map(grp ->
                      GroupedObservable.from(grp.getKey(),grp.takeWhile(t -> keySelector.call(t).equals(grp.getKey())))
                );
    }
}
```

I get this output:

```
[Alpha, Adam, Apple, Axe]
[Beta, Brick, Bridge, Bat]
[Gamma, Gorilla]
```

When I really want this:

```
[Alpha, Adam, Apple]
[Beta, Brick, Bridge, Bat]
[Gamma, Gorilla]
[Axe]
```

What can I do so that an ordered set of emissions will `onComplete()` the `GroupedObservable` when the key changes?

Comment: Just realized my work above is broken. Still need a solution though.

Answer (score 1):

Coordinating completion of the `GroupedObservable` across the `groupBy` operator is a pretty tricky thing (though synchronous processing in your case may enable other solutions). For this reason, `groupBy` has an overload that allows you to specify a `mapFactory`. If you use Guava `CacheBuilder` as per javadoc on the `groupBy` overload then you can specify a max size of 1 for the map and your desired behaviour results:

```
Func1<String,String> keySelectory = s -> s.substring(0,1);
Func1<String,String> elementSelectory = s -> s;
Func1<Action1<String>, Map<String, String>> mapFactory =
   action -> 
     CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
       .maximumSize(1)
       .removalListener(notification ->
          action.call(notification.getKey()))
     .<String, String> build().asMap();
items.groupBy(keySelector, elementSelector, mapFactory)
            .flatMap(grp -> grp.toList())
            .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Google was worried it was tricky. Alright let me process this information... ill need to mess with that part of Guava.

Comment: added an explicit example for ya

Comment: @DaveMoten After fixing compile errors, code execution result is single notification:[axe] - which is far far away from what OP was expected. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Such problems are best solved with custom operators - transformations which depend on state (here, already processed items and their keys) are not the best target for reactive approach, and often require `Subjects`. With built-in operators, (verbose) solution for cold observables can be as follows:

```
public static <K, T> Observable.Transformer<T, GroupedObservable<K, T>> groupByUntilChanged(Func1<? super T, ? extends K> keyExtractor) {
    return observable -> groupByUntilChanged(observable, keyExtractor);
}

static <K, T> Observable<GroupedObservable<K, T>> groupByUntilChanged(Observable<T> itemsStream,
                                                                      Func1<? super T, ? extends K> keyExtractor) {

    /*keys according to keyExtractor */
    Observable<K> keysStream = itemsStream.distinctUntilChanged(keyExtractor).map(keyExtractor);
    Func1<K, Func1<T, Boolean>> itemByKey = key -> item -> key.equals(keyExtractor.call(item));

    /*predicate functions to match sub stream specified by key extractor*/
    Observable<Func1<T, Boolean>> itemsByKeyFuncStream = keysStream.map(itemByKey);

    /*stream chunks are processed sequentially, some kind of state bookkeeping is needed: let it be the number of
      already processed items */
    BehaviorSubject<Integer> skipCountStream = BehaviorSubject.create(0);

    Observable<GroupedObservable<K, T>> groupByUntilChangedStream = itemsByKeyFuncStream.concatMap(takeF ->

            /*skip already processed items, take while key extractor predicate is true*/
            skipCountStream.first().map(count -> itemsStream.skip(count).takeWhile(takeF)))

            .doOnNext(subItems ->
                    /*once group is ready, increase number of already processed items*/
                    subItems.count()
                            .flatMap(subItemsSize -> skipCountStream.first().map(allSize -> allSize + subItemsSize))
                            .subscribe(skipCountStream::onNext))
             /*convert to GroupedObservable*/
            .zipWith(keysStream, (obs, key) -> GroupedObservable.from(key, obs));

    return groupByUntilChangedStream;
}
```

It was tested with

```
Observable<String> itemsStream =
            Observable.just("Alpha", "Adam", "Apple", "Beta", "Brick", "Bridge", "Bat", "Gamma", "Gorilla", "Axe");
    Func1<String, String> keyExtractor = s -> s.substring(0, 1);
    Observable<GroupedObservable<String, String>> groupByUntilChangedStream = itemsStream.compose(groupByUntilChanged(keyExtractor));

    /*groups starting with "A"*/
    groupByUntilChangedStream
            .filter(grouped -> grouped.getKey().equals("A"))
            .flatMap(Observable::toList)
            .defaultIfEmpty(Collections.emptyList())
            .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

And result was

```
[Alpha, Adam, Apple]
[Axe]
```

Comment: Okay, wow. This just took my mind for a spin. I need to study it a little more but this is pretty clever. I wish there was a way to not have a `toList()` or a `Subject`. But I think there are some awesome ideas in here. Let me play with it and I'll mark as answer later.

Comment: `.toList().map(List::size)` part should be replaced with `count()`. As for subjects, i am very interested to see solution without them